# Angular 4 checkbox change value

Tags: angular, typescript

how could you achieve in Angular 4 that when you register in a checkbox save an "A" or "B" value. As much as I try, he is only sending me true or false, I hope someone can help me.

registry.component.ts

```
  this.userForm = new FormGroup({
   state: new FormControl('',),
  });
```

registry.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>State</label>
  <input type="checkbox"
         [(ngModel)]="isChecked"
         (change)="checkValue(isChecked?'A':'B')"
         formControlName="state"/>
</div>  

<pre>{{userForm.value | json}}</pre>
```

That way I can get the console to show the value I want (A or B) but in the JSON is still true or false.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

This it what you are looking for:

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="checkValue(isChecked?'A':'B')" />
```

Inside your class:

```js
checkValue(event: any){
   console.log(event);
}
```

**Also include FormsModule in `app.module.ts` to make ngModel work !**

Hope it Helps!

Comment: With your answer I can see that the value changes in the console ("A", "B"), but I have to add that in the registry I sent a JSON, agrunpando in a FormGroup and FormControl, in the JSON it continues sending true or false , any help on how to fix that?

Comment: Is there a way you can parse it ?
I can't understand your current problem, !

Comment: Simple and easy solution but in my browser console it was saying that "It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7." yet it still working. will it work for long time or what? can you please explain?

Comment: It worked for me with this:
 `checkValue(event: any){`
   `console.log(event.currentTarget.checked);`
`}`

Answer (score 108):

Give a try on this,

**Template**

```
<input (change)="fieldsChange($event)" value="angular" type="checkbox"/>
```

**Ts File**

```
fieldsChange(values:any):void {
  console.log(values.currentTarget.checked);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, set the parameter type to `(event:Event)` instead of `(values:any)` and access the checked attribute via `(event.target as HTMLInputElement).checked`

Comment: Also, you can bind the checkbox to the model with `[checked]="isChecked"`

Answer (score 37):

```
changed = (evt) => {    
this.isChecked = evt.target.checked;
}

<input type="checkbox" [checked]="checkbox" (change)="changed($event)" id="no"/>
```

Comment: Please don't just dump a code block as an answer. A good answer explains the solution and gives some context.

Comment: $event.target.checked is what I was looking for, as opposed to $event.target.value for inputs

Answer (score 19):

We can do below. I am using angular 12.

[Html]

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="lock" (change)="changeStatus($event)" />
```

[TS]

```
changeStatus(event:Event){
    const isChecked = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).checked;
    console.log(isChecked)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I am guessing that this is what something you are trying to achieve.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="a" (click)="click($event)">A
<input type="checkbox" value="b" (click)="click($event)">B

click(ev){
   console.log(ev.target.defaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Another approach is to use `ngModelChange`:

Template:

```
<input type="checkbox" ngModel (ngModelChange)="onChecked(obj, $event)" />
```

Controller:

```
onChecked(obj: any, isChecked: boolean){
  console.log(obj, isChecked); // {}, true || false
}
```

I prefer this method because here you get the relevant object and `true`/`false` values of a checkbox.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me, angular 9:

component.html file:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="checkValue($event)">text</mat-checkbox>
```

component.ts file:

```
checkValue(e){console.log(e.target.checked);}
```

Comment: I needed to use `e.target.checked` for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="record.status" (change)="changeStatus(record.id,$event)">
```

And on your ts file,

```
changeStatus(id, e) {
    var status = e.target.checked;
    this.yourseverice.changeStatus(id, status).subscribe(result => {
        if (status)
            this.notify.success(this.l('AddedAsKeyPeople'));
        else
            this.notify.success(this.l('RemovedFromKeyPeople'));

    });
}
```

Here, record is the model for current row and status is boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

try this worked for me :

```
checkValue(event: any) {
    this.siteSelected.majeur = event;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component class:

```
checkValue(event: any) {
  this.userForm.patchValue({
    state: event
  })
}
```

Now in controls you have value A or B

Answer (score 0):

You can use form controller valueChanges() listener and subscribe for its events,  for example

> On your controller or .ts file

```
constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
            this.yourForm = this.createFrom();
            this.listenForCheckboxChanges();
           
  }

  private createFrom() {
     return this._formBuilder.group(
          {
            CheckBox:[false],
    
          })
  }

  get yourCheckbox(){
    return this.conservationForm.controls['CheckBox'];
  }

  listenForCheckboxChanges() {
    this.yourCheckbox.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
      //console vaule of checkbox
      console.log(res)
    });
  }
```

> on your view or .htm file

```
<div  [formGroup]="yourForm" fxLayoutGap="12px">
  <mat-checkbox  formControlName="CheckBox">Checkbox!</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```