# How to pass the checked and unchecked value of checkboxes in component.ts file in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a checkbox which looks like this:

[image]

It is iterating through json data as :

[image]

The code looks like :

```
<div class="card-body">
   <h5>Document List</h5>
   <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let document of documents">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1"  [value]= "document.docId"
      name="document.docName" (click)="callMe(document.docId)" >{{document.docName}}
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

And i want operation like when the user selects the checkboxes then I tried to pass the id to the component.ts file.In this method **(click)="callMe(document.docId)"** if the boxes is checked then id is coming as in **component.ts** file is

```
callMe(id:any){
  console.log(id);
}
```

[image]

But when i uncheck one of the checkbox the problem occuring is

Fig 2.
[image]

document.ts file is:

```
export class Document {

    docId:number;
    docName:number;

}
```

Comment: Provide your full code to understand whats going wrong

Comment: Can't you use template driven forms?

Comment: Check this question - this might help you with your requirement
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068222/angular-4-checkbox-change-value?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'src/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  documents = [
    {
      docId:1,
      docName:'Proforma Invoice',
      checked: true
    },
    {
      docId:2,
      docName:'Packing List',
      checked: false
    }
  ];

  checkboxClicked() {
    this.documents.filter(x => x.checked).map(x => {
      console.log(x.docId);
    })
  }

}
```

**Note:** You should not pass id as checkbox value. Create some boolean property with the object.

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let document of documents">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox{{document.docId}}" [(ngModel)]="document.checked" (change)="checkboxClicked()" />
</ng-container>
```

Comment: When i copied and paste your code in html the such error came "ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions."

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox{{document.docId}}" [(ngModel)]="document.checked" (change)="checkboxClicked()" />

Add a name to the checkbox field like above

Answer (score 1):

```
    callMe(id:any,event){
      if(event.target.checked)
       {  
        console.log(id);
       }
    }

<div class="card-body">
   <h5>Document List</h5>
   <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let document of documents">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1"  [value]= "document.docId"
      name="document.docName" (click)="callMe(document.docId,$event)" >{{document.docName}}
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: from where the value you are getting this.checked?

Comment: this refers to checkbox

Comment: i am not getting what are you doing

Comment: you pass $event from template then use that event  to get target and check the checked property on target

Comment: brother but in this callMe(id:any,event) method if i uncheck the box then its id is still showing in console

Answer (score 1):

You have to use combination of `$event` and `id`

```
callMe(event, id) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```

And in the template file like below

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1" [value]="document.docId" name="document.docName" (change)="callMe($event, document.docId)">{{document.docName}}
```

Working stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scjex1)

Comment: yes brother but when i uncheck one of the box then the id should be removed from console? how to get this?

Comment: @ashwinkarki once value is printed in the console, it can't be removed until unless you clear it manually. Did you check the stackblitz I provided?

Comment: yes i need to only pass the id of checked checkbox. if it is unchecked then it should not appear in console.