# How to call different methods when checkbox is checked/unchecked in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

In my component class, I have two methods, one for when a checkbox is checked, and one for when a checkbox is unchecked. how do I define this behavior in my template file? this is sort of a pseudo-code of what I expected to have functionality for, though after some time looking around the web I don't see any option like this and can't seem to understand how it should be done

```
<input type="checkbox" *when checked*="method1()" *when unchecked*="method2()">
```

how should I implement this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068222/angular-4-checkbox-change-value/47068667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this as below :

in `component.html` :

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="handleChange()" />
```

in `component.ts` :

```
handleChange() {
    console.log(this.isChecked);
    if (this.isChecked) {
      this.checkedTrue();
    } else {
      this.checkedFalse();
    }

  }

  checkedTrue() {
    console.log('checked')
  }

  checkedFalse() {
    console.log('unchecked')
}
```

here is the working demo : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pu1oho)

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense, just to make it fully clear for me (really new to Angular), the [(ngModel)] is holding the value of a checkbox and "isChecked" could be replaced with gibberish (i.e, just a name)?

Comment: Its called `two way binding`. you can read here :  https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-data-binding/  . you `bind ` the Variable stored in `ts` file  directly with dom element. Any change gets reflected in both the side.