# How can i check Template and get the value of it?

Tags: node.js, angular

Well My purpose is to use checkbox to pick a template,after that it will be added to  a database
but when i try to get the code of template into value it always display undefined.

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhPig.png)

```
Html Code: 
<input type="checkbox" id="templatepick" name="picker" value="item.templatebodyclient" (change)="displaydata($event)">
```

templatebody attribut have the html of our template so i tried to get it from the checked template value to be set in database

```
Typescript code:

displaydata(event: { checked: any; }){
   console.log("",event.checked)  }
```

Any idea how i can solve this ? or another idea could be useful and thanks

Comment: please prefer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068222/angular-4-checkbox-change-value/47068667

Comment: i saw it before i come to ask here and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="templatepick" name="picker" [value]="item.templatebodyclient" (change)="displaydata($event)">
```

TS

```
displaydata(event: any) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.checked) 
  console.log(event.target.checked) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i change it to mat-checkbox and i put the value of it to ${{item.templatebodyclient}} instead of "item.templatebodyclient"

Comment: Yes, event.checked will work on mat-checkbox