# How to toggle class in parent (tr) when checkbox is checked in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to toggle class in **tr** when checkbox is checked. I am trying to learn angular pls guide me as a easiest way.

```
<tr class="unchecked_checkbox">
   <td>
      <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="two" id="flexCheckDefault" />
         <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault" />
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass), which allows you to have conditional classes over the element. So you just need to make the element look to the value that is going to be changed when the checkbox is marked.

Example:

```html
<tr [ngClass]="{unchecked_checkbox: !two, checked_checkbox: two}">
  <td>
      <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="two" id="flexCheckDefault" />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
          </label>
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Error: src/app/home/home.component.html:45:88 - error TS2339: Property 'active' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'.

45                         <tr [ngClass]="{unchecked_checkbox: !active, checked_checkbox: active}">

This error apears

Comment: You need to use the variable that you are assign on your TS file as the conditional. That variable must exist in the component TS file, and when you check or uncheck the checkbox the value of it must change

Comment: If have doubts about how to handle the values within variables, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068222/angular-4-checkbox-change-value).

Comment: `[class.unchecked_checkbox]="!two" [class.checked_checkbox]="two"` is usually cleaner than `[ngClass]`. Of course I would use `:not(.checked_checkbox)` in CSS and have just the one class

Comment: I do preferer the [ngClass] notation, but for sure the idea of using the :not in CSS is much better. I totally forgot about it.